# How to make a game type in Halo Reach?

Tags: halo-reach

I created a map on forge, and I want a game type to go with it. I Chose invasion slayer because it has classes, and is meant for big maps. But when I try to test it on custom game, it says this map does not fit this game type. What do I do?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking here. Do you want to know how to choose a game type properly for your map or how to make the map work with your chosen game type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place certain objects in your map before it will support invasion slayer. I found a guide in a [forum post](http://www.forgehub.com/forum/reach-forge-discussion/115195-invasion-slayer.html#post1313448) by EternalEnmity. It says:

> Here is a halfway decent guide in making Invasion Slayer maps.
>
> 1. You need to have at MOST 6 initial spawn points for each team. They need to be labeled INVASION and set to the proper team.
> 2. You need backfield spawns. A backfield Spawn is an area that is available to either all fireteams or some of them in all phases.
>      (Fireteam-each team is split into 3 mini-teams. Each player in a
>      mini-team has a partner they can choose to spawn by, those miniteams
>      are called Fireteams) A good number of backfield spawn zones to put
>      are 3. Set each spawn zones spawn sequence to 0, 1, 2 or 3. 0, 1 and 2
>      are each individual fireteam. Setting it 3 will make it available to
>      all fireteams. You must label it INV_SLAYER_RES_ZONE
> 3. You HAVE to have at least 1 Drop zone. This will be labeled as INV_SLAYER_DROP. Set all the spawn sequences to either the same, or
>      chronological order. This will decide which ones spawn before the
>      others. Set all the same for random choosing. Now, I'm not exactly
>      sure whether or not you can choose which weapons came out of a drop,
>      or in which phase. But I don't see why you shouldn't be able to.
>
> Last notes:
>
> Unlike The normal Invasion, you cannot phase or gate objects. This
>   means you can't have objects spawn and/or delete themselves upon
>   phases.
>
> Blue team is Elites, Red team is Spartans.
>
> Vehicles labeled with CREATED_VEHICLES make it so a vehicle is
>   indestructable for 5 seconds upon spawning.
>
> Never EVER use the labels INV_PLATFORM or INV_MANCANNON as those or
>   specific to the huge gravity lift, and the mancannons, respectively,
>   that spawn in Spire in the 3rd phase of Invasion

Comment: _"Never EVER use the labels INV_PLATFORM or INV_MANCANNON"_ What if I want my map to have giant mancannons that shoot players to the sky :P